# Проблемы с созданием своих методов встроенного объекта String

Tags: javascript, строки

В общем проблема вот в чем:
Есть вот такой вот код

```
String.prototype.isEmail = function() {
        var str = this.valueOf(), 
        regExp =  /^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/;

        return regExp.test(this.valueOf());
}
```

Вот этот метод, просто проверяет что строка - Email.
Проблема вот в чем:
При исползовании метода, на пример `"AZAZA".isEmail()` работает правильно, но

при использовании его уже дальше, он меняет свои значения с на пример false на постоянный true. И это не зименить обратно.
Меняется все эт дело данный код, я понятия не имею, как это происходит.

```
if ("wdwd".isEmail() === false){  
    //Вот после этого он теперь превращается в true если это не email
    console.log(isEmail)
    if (onTemplateEror){
        onTemplateEror.call(this, el, 2, obj);
    }
    errors.errListFromTemplate.push(el);
}
```

При этом до этого он всегда выводи правильные значения.
В чем проблема? Может я что-то не то написал? Или же все-таки проблема внутри JS

Comment: "console.log(isEmail)" - что здесь `isEmail`?

Comment: сделай [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть ошибку. [В вопрос можно встраивать сниппеты](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999)

Answer (score 0):

там находится ода типа `elVal.isEmail()` elVal - это строка, приходящая из полей ввода.